# How to save the table content along with the table on the Win32 clipboard

Tags: c++, winapi

The `CF_TEXT` clipboard format supports the plain text but I want to store the whole table with the content. I  think Rich Text format will help me to take the whole data with the table. Can anyone help show me exactly how to get the data with the table using win32 in C++ so that I can copy the whole table (from local machine) and paste it (in remote system)?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for exactly. Are you asking how to get the table data in a RichText format to begin with? Or how to place it on the clipboard? Or how to read it from the clipboard? Please clarify your question, and also explain what you have already tried that hasn't worked for you

Comment: @Remy Lebeau:Hi "Are you asking how to get the table data in a RichText format to begin with?" Yes i want to get the data from clip Board not as text (as this am able to with CF_TEXT) but want to get data in Rich text format or HTML format .

Comment: You are still not being clear. Is the table data ALREADY on the clipboard and you just want to read it? You can query the clipboard to see if a specific format is on the clipboard, or enumerate all of the formats that are on the clipboard. Or, do you want to get the data from somewhere else in your app and PUT it on the clipboard?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau :Yes I want to  enumerate all of the formats that are on the clipboard how to enumarate  could you please help me, example Rich text format.
 Basically i want to get excel or word data with formatted .. but when am doing getclipboarddata am getting paint text  format...

Comment: "*I want to  enumerate all of the formats that are on the clipboard*" - look at [`EnumClipboardFormats()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumclipboardformats) and [`IsClipboardFormatAvailable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-isclipboardformatavailable).

Comment: "*example Rich text format*" - that is not a predefined format, so you need to use [`RegisterClipboardFormat("Rich Text Format")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerclipboardformatw) to get the correct ID for that format, then you can read/set data for that format. "*Basically i want to get excel or word data with formatted .. but when am doing getclipboarddata am getting paint text format...*" - well, of course, if you are reading the data in `CF_TEXT` format, then you will get plain text only.